# Export all created conda environments

Tags: conda

I know how to export a specific conda environment:

```
conda activate myenv
conda env export > myenv.yaml
```

But how can I automatically export *all* created conda environments (in separate yaml files, whose name corresponds to the name of the environment)?

Comment: @FlyingTeller zsh (but I presume that for this matter that is equivalent to bash)

Comment: @FlyingTeller No I'm really looking to save my conda environments such that I can retrieve them should that ever be needed. Call it a backup strategy. (I edit a bit in the hope that my question is clearer)

Comment: Sorry, must admit I misread the question

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't need to activate the environment. `conda env export` accepts the argument `-n <env name>` which you can combine with a `for` loop over the output of `conda list`:

```
for env in $(conda env list | cut -d" " -f1); do 
   if [[ ${env:0:1} == "#" ]] ; then continue; fi;
   conda env export -n $env > ${env}.yml
done
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot. I guess the only a bit dirty hack is the `tail -n+4`. In particular, I only get two lines of comment. So a bit more general would be to remove the `tail` and add `if [[ ${env:0:1} == "#" ]] ; then continue; fi;` in the for-loop.

Comment: Thanks, I put in the recommendation. Feel free to edit, if you see an improvement :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `conda env export -n $env > ${env}.yml`?

Answer (score 0):

```
conda env list > ToENV
sed -i '1,4d' ToENV # remove first 4 lines
awk  '{ print " conda pack -n "$1 " -o "$1}' ToENV | sed 's~$~.tar.gz~g' > BACK.sh
```

Open `BACK.sh` and review and remove those line you don't need.

```
bash BACK.sh
```