# How do I export all conda environments?

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file, conda, backup

I would like to export all my conda libraries in one go.

So the question was partly answered in this post:
[Export all created conda environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60508333/export-all-created-conda-environments)

```
for env in $(conda env list | cut -d" " -f1); do 
   if [[ ${env:0:1} == "#" ]] ; then continue; fi;
   conda env export -n $env > ${env}.yml
done
```

but since i'm not so experienced, or perhaps plain stupid, my question is:
** where and how do I run this piece of code on a win10 machine?**

running it in conda doesn't work, cmd prompt also fails
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeJVf.png)

do I need to put it in a script?
Or is this solution simply not going to work on windows?

Comment: This is bash code. You either need to run bash shell (e.g., GitBash) or convert it to a Windows-specific version (e.g., Batch or PowerShell).

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:

1. put the script in a notepad file
2. rename the extention to .bat
3. run it from windows explorer

improved on the script as following:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('conda env list ^| findstr /r /c:"^[^#]" ^| findstr /v /r /c:"^base" ^| %__APPDIR__%more.com +1') do (
    echo %%a
    call :export_env "%%a"
)

pause
goto :eof

:export_env
setlocal
set input_string=%~1
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a in ("%input_string%") do (
    set env_name=%%a
    set path1=%%b
)
conda env export -n %env_name% > %env_name%.yml
echo %env_name%.yml
endlocal
```

Comment: Way too complicated IMHO, just use `tokens=1` and instead of the `call`, run `conda env export -n %%a > %%a.yml`

Answer (score 0):

Modified Ritchie's great answer so the script will also export environments created with path (-p) and not name (-n). The script uses the parent directory's name as save name (under the assumption the environment is in a repo's subfolder whose name is ".*", e.g. ".env", ".build", ".test"...).

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=1" %%a in ('conda env list ^| findstr /r /c:"^[^#]" ^| findstr /r /c:"\..*$" ^| findstr /v /r /c:"^base" ^| %__APPDIR__%more.com +1') do (
    call :export_env "%%a"
)
for /f "tokens=1" %%a in ('conda env list ^| findstr /r /c:"^[^#]" ^| findstr /v /r /c:"\..*$" ^| findstr /v /r /c:"^base" ^| %__APPDIR__%more.com +1') do (
    echo "conda env export -n %%a > %%a.yml"
    call conda env export -n %%a > %%a.yml
)

pause
goto :eof

:export_env
setlocal
set s=%~1
for %%b in (%s%.) do set parent=%%~dpb
FOR %%a IN ("%parent:~0,-1%") DO SET env_name=%%~nxa
echo "conda env export -p %s% > %env_name%.yml"
call conda env export -p %s% > %env_name%.yml
endlocal
```